# SXSSFSheet autoSizeColumn error on apache poi 4.1.2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

My project using Spring Boot. I try to export data to excel file with `org.apache.poi 4.1.2` , i use method `autoSizeColumn` to auto size column

```
headerRow.forEach(item -> {
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(item.getColumnIndex());
});
```

but i get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not auto-size column. Make sure the column was tracked prior to auto-sizing the column.
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(SXSSFSheet.java:1591)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(SXSSFSheet.java:1545)
```

how to fix this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue following this link [SXSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn is throwing IllegalStateException](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60036)

i resolve this issue by using the method `public void trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing()` of class [SXSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing--)

> public void trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing()
>
> Tracks all columns in the sheet for auto-sizing. If this is called,
> individual columns do not need to be tracked. Because determining the
> best-fit width for a cell is expensive, this may affect the
> performance.
>
> Since:
> 3.14beta1

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above issue with the following, do this only after you are done rendering everything on to the sheet

if you have list for columns then the following will work fine.

```
// autoSizing of the columns

for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
  workbookSheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
  workbookSheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

For your case the below will work.

```
headerRow.forEach(item -> {
  sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(item.getColumnIndex());
});
```